# Should meta.stackoverflow.com have badges?

Tags: discussion

As the title says, should meta.stackoverflow.com have badges?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is a meta question about meta.stackoverflow.com. Meta discussions of this type clutters the site -- it should be deleted or moved to http://meta.meta.stackoverflow.com.

Now, should http://meta.meta.stackoverflow.com have badges?

/s

Comment: Great! Discussing about meta.meta badges would involve a third additional layer though.

Comment: Smart answer. Deserved to be upvoted X1000

Comment: Not to worry, Douglas Hofstadter will tell you that in order to resolve this, we will just define supermeta.stackoverflow.com - this is the logical extension of meta.meta...meta.stackoverflow.com to infinity and you are able to have meta discussions at the infinity level on this site.

Comment: Best answer possible.

Answer (score 8):

Sure, why not? A higher reputation on this site indicates that one cares about SO and adds to the debates about how SO can be improved. Something similar can be argued w.r.t. badges.

On the other hand: most people coming here will be SO members already, so they don't need the addictive effect that badges have on new users.

Answer (score 4):

In meta-discussions, reputation score, badges, upvotes and downvotes all lost their sense.

Comment: I disagree that upvotes and downvotes lost their sense. They are an indication of the (dis)approval of the rest of the community.

Comment: Surely the mechanism is still needed, but default ordering by votes makes discussions... something else.

Answer (score 3):

The point of badges is to encourage good behaviors, and that's just as important here on the meta site as it is on the main site.

Answer (score 1):

I'd vote for a "Meta" badge that you get once you got enough "normal" badges. Maybe like 20 badges give a bronze Meta badge.

Comment: Does the meta badge appear on SOFU? Is encouraging badge-whoring on those sites through (ab)using meta desired? .. Now I want one, but I already have user profile > accounts, too.